# Which primes $\mathfrak{p}$ can be written as sums of two squares in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, cubics, sums-of-squares, class-field-theory

which primes $\mathfrak{p}$ can be written as sums of two squares in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$?  I am asking to solve an equation:

$$ \mathfrak{p} = \big(a_1+a_2\sqrt[3]{2}+a_3\sqrt[3]{4}\big)^2 
 + \big(b_1+b_2\sqrt[3]{2}+b_3\sqrt[3]{4}\big)^2 $$

I am still figuring out the code in `Sage` or `PARI/GP`.  Perhaps there's a lattice or ideal $I \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$ such that this sum-of-squares equation has a solution iff $\mathfrak{p} \in I$. Have no idea really

---

Why do I have hope for asking this question?  Here's an vaguely related example from an article of [Jared Weinstein](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2016-53-01/S0273-0979-2015-01515-6/):

> $x^4 - 2$ splits modulo $p$ iff $p = a^2 + 64b^2$ for integers $a$ and $b$.

This becomes a statement about algebraic number fields:

> Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(i)$ and $L = K(\sqrt[4]{2})$ .
>
> This means $[L:K]=4$ and $[K:\mathbb{Q}]= 2$ so that $[L:\mathbb{Q}]=[L:K][K:\mathbb{Q}]=4 \times 2 = 8$.
>
> Let $p = a^2 + 64b^2$ and $a \equiv 1 \pmod 8$, then $p = \pi \overline{\pi}$ where $\pi \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a Gaussian prime and $\pi \equiv 1 \pmod{ 8 \mathbb{Z}[i]}$ and so $p$ splits in $L$.

Comment: 4+25=29       I'd start with that as the answer to the first question part.

Comment: Is your prime $\mathfrak p$ an ideal (as the notation would hint), or an integral element, in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt[3]2\,]$? Not precisely the same thing, since the generator of an ideal is defined only up to a unit…

Comment: @Lubin I haven't even done the appropriate computer work yet... At the moment the exercise has been merely to *state* the question and check that it has content.  i'd prefer numbers, but this is Number Theory so they could be ideals... E.g. generate a list of prime numbers (or ideals) in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt[3]{2}]$

Comment: Step 1: Find out for which prime ideals $-1$ is a quadratic residue.  Step 2: Find necessary conditions on the residue classes of sums of two squares modulo $4$. Step 3: Read about Hilbert's first  supplementary law.